# Lots of errors in Android Project on opening Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, build-target

I created and built my android project successfully. I close the Eclipse and reopen it and have lots of errors. I clean and refresh and rebuild my project but the error is not disappeared.

I open project properties (Alt+Enter), change the project build target to any other API and apply it and again I select my previous API and click OK.

Now everything is OK and my project is built successfully.

Why? Why the build target is not selected after opening the Eclipse and I have to reselect it?

How can I solve it permanently?

Comment: Start using Android Studio.

Comment: Did you changed the Api level in manifest?

Comment: @JoelFernandes Android Studio is too heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check your "AndroidManifest.xml".

**Edit:**

You should check if SDK versions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

are in the existing installed APIs.

Comment: Very general answer. Checking what?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: do you have these? Im also new to android.

Comment: Also right-click ur project, and select properties - android. Then you can choose project build target.

Comment: your answer text should be in comment...or you can make a list of possibilities which causes error(what u asked in comment ) should be in answer

Comment: Thanks, The problem was that. My selected `SdkVersion` in Manifest was not in the list of installed APIs of my SDK. I changed them to one of the existing APIs and the problem solved.